# If an investor wants to reinvest dividends, aren't stock dividends better than cash dividends?

Tags: stocks, dividends, dividend-reinvestment, stock-dividend

When a company pays a cash dividend, the shareholders may need to pay income tax on that dividend. If a shareholder always wishes to reinvest the dividends, cash dividends have a few disadvantages:

- The shareholder always has to do work during dividend season to reinvest the dividends.
- The stock price is unlikely to be an exact multiple of the cash dividend, so the investor will have some cash left-over that is not reinvested.
- Dividends are tax-inefficient as mentioned above.

For such an investor, a stock dividend (as opposed to a cash dividend) may be a better choice because:

1. Dividends are "reinvested" automatically.
2. Whenever the investor needs cash, he/she can create a cash dividend simply by selling the extra shares given in the stock dividend. In effect, a stock dividend has an "optional cash dividend" within it.

I noticed that cash dividends are significantly more common than stock dividends. So my questions are:

- Are stock dividends really better than cash dividends for investors who want to reinvest dividends?
- Given the apparent efficiencies of stock dividends, why do companies continue to pay cash dividends and not stock dividends?

Comment: You use the phrase average investor, but don't you mean investor in individual stocks. Many people own stock through their 401(k), or mutual fund, or ETF. They don't see most of the pros or cons.

Comment: Similar: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/57346/why-do-people-always-talk-about-stocks-that-pay-high-dividends?rq=1 https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/125632/if-your-plan-is-to-reinvest-dividends-wouldnt-you-rather-the-company-not-pay-d

Answer (score 1):

- I don't know of the American tax system, but I could imagine that on stock dividends, income tax would be due as well (not necessarily immediately, but at a later time).
- The argument

  > The shareholder always has to do work during dividend season to reinvest the dividends.

  can be weighed against

  > Whenever the investor needs cash, he/she can create a cash dividend simply by selling the extra shares given in the stock dividend. In effect, a stock dividend has an "optional cash dividend" within it.

  because, if you see it the other way: if you need cash, you don't need to do anything; if you want to re-invest, you can do so. (It's not so much work; it's usually just a matter of some clicks.) Besides, the 2nd argument can be reversed: "Whenever the investor doesn't need cash, he/she can create a stock dividend simply by buying shares. In effect, a "cash dividend" has an "optional stock dividend" within it." It's (kind of) the same amount of work.
- > The stock price is unlikely to be an exact multiple of the cash dividend, so the investor will have some cash left-over that is not reinvested.

  That's right, but personally, in this case, I'd just fill up with additional funds.

A third option (which some companies indeed choose) would be to pay no dividend at all or to pay a very small dividend. In this case, the increasing value of the company is reflected by increasing stock price. Remember that the value of a stock drops about the amount of the dividend when the dividend is paid.

Comment: In the US, stock dividends tend not to be taxable when received but there are some exceptions which can be found in IRS publication 550.